# Intercept HTTP requests using elixir

Tags: elixir, rate-limiting

I'm new to elixir. I'm trying to look for a package that intercepts HTTP requests using elixir, so I could process it in the backend. The reason why I need elixir is to implement rate limit error, for which I found hammer to have a neat syntax and vital functionalities (docs at - https://hexdocs.pm/hammer/Hammer.html#summary ). The implementation is as follows - if it is a rate limit error, it raises rate limit error, if not it is redirected to the actual application (which was not done using elixir). The issue here is that the function `check_rate` uses `bucket ID` as a parameter and not the URL. Is there any way I could intercept requests and check for rate limit error? Appreciate if you could explain it with an example code

Comment: I think you might get better responses here if you clarified your question.  Are you trying to use Elixir as an API gateway that limits requests?  Hammer can use any string as a bucket name, so that could be a URL or a parameter, or anything. The `hammer-plug` package might be useful to you, but I think you need to re-work your question so it's more clear what you're trying to do.